# Lego Mindstorms ev3 leJOS finding libraries during compilation

Tags: java, eclipse, git, ant, compilation

I tried to set up leJOS in eclipse, and imported all the libraries from git, but I am having trouble compiling using the ant build. Here is my build file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<project name="SimonSais" basedir="." default="copy">
<property name="source.dir"     value="src"/>
<property name="lib.dir"        value="../ev3/ev3classes"/>
<property name="class.dir"      value="build"/>
<property name="jar.dir"        value="dist"/>
<property name="main-class"     value="SimonSais"/>
<property name="lejos.home"     value="/home/root/lejos"/>
<property name="ev3.host"       value="10.0.1.1"/>

<path id="libraries.path">    
    <fileset dir="${lib.dir}">
        <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
</path>

<target name="clean" description="delete old files">
    <delete dir="${class.dir}"/>
    <delete dir="${jar.dir}"/>
</target>

<target name="compile" description="build class files" depends="clean">
    <mkdir dir="${class.dir}"/>
    <javac srcdir="${source.dir}" destdir="${class.dir}">
        <classpath refid="libraries.path"/>
    </javac>
</target>

<target name="jar" depends="compile">
    <mkdir dir="${jar.dir}"/>
    <jar destfile="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar" basedir="${class.dir}">
        <manifest>
            <attribute name="Main-Class" value="${main-class}"/>
            <attribute name="Class-Path" value="${lejos.home}/lib/ev3classes.jar ${lejos.home}/libjna/usr/share/java/jna.jar"/>
        </manifest>
    </jar>  
</target>

<target name="copy" depends="jar">
    <scp todir="root:@${ev3.host}:/home/lejos/programs/" trust="true">
        <fileset file="${jar.dir}/${ant.project.name}.jar"/>
    </scp>
</target>
```

But when I try to run it sais ..ev3/ev3classes doesn't exist. This is being caused by the classes being referenced in the workspace, but not actually copied there. That is the way it said to do it, though.

They also said you may need to change 'lib.dir', but I don't exactly know where to set it to. I tried setting it to where the classes are actually located (C:\Users\soc0001\git\ev3\ev3classes) but it gives me compile errors saying it cannot find the packages:

```
Compiling 1 source file to D:\School\Programs\Lego Mindstorms\SimonSais\build
[javac] D:\School\Programs\Lego Mindstorms\SimonSais\src\SimonSais.java:1: error: package lejos.hardware does not exist
[javac] import lejos.hardware.Button;
[javac]                      ^
[javac] D:\School\Programs\Lego Mindstorms\SimonSais\src\SimonSais.java:2: error: package lejos.hardware.lcd does not exist
[javac] import lejos.hardware.lcd.LCD;
[javac]                          ^
[javac] D:\School\Programs\Lego Mindstorms\SimonSais\src\SimonSais.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         LCD.clear();
[javac]         ^
[javac]   symbol:   variable LCD
[javac]   location: class SimonSais
[javac] D:\School\Programs\Lego Mindstorms\SimonSais\src\SimonSais.java:8: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         LCD.drawString("First EV3 Program", 0, 5);
[javac]         ^
[javac]   symbol:   variable LCD
[javac]   location: class SimonSais
[javac] D:\School\Programs\Lego Mindstorms\SimonSais\src\SimonSais.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         Button.waitForAnyPress();
[javac]         ^
[javac]   symbol:   variable Button
[javac]   location: class SimonSais
[javac] D:\School\Programs\Lego Mindstorms\SimonSais\src\SimonSais.java:10: error: cannot finsymbol
[javac]         LCD.clear();
[javac]         ^
[javac]   symbol:   variable LCD
[javac]   location: class SimonSais
[javac] D:\School\Programs\Lego Mindstorms\SimonSais\src\SimonSais.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
[javac]         LCD.refresh();
[javac]         ^
[javac]   symbol:   variable LCD
[javac]   location: class SimonSais
```

I am not sure exactly how the build file is meant to look like, and what to set the lib.dir to. Could someone please give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The compile target only references `libraries.path` as a classpath:

```
<classpath refid="libraries.path"/>
```

Make sure the right jar dependencies are in that path (meaning are in `lib.dir`).

The [OP user2971198](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2971198/user2971198) confirms [in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20795629/lego-mindstorms-ev3-lejos-finding-libraries-during-compilation/20796362#comment31180629_20796362):

> I simply forgot (although it is never mentioned) to build the projects that were imported with their ant scripts first.
>   That's why it didn't find any jar [(in `lib.dir`)].

Comment: I simply forgot (Although it never mentioned) to build the projects that were imported with their ant scripts first. That's why it didn't find any jar.